How can I apply <ogc:And> inside <ogc:Function name="if_then_else">
The example:
<CssParameter name="fill">
  <ogc:Function name="if_then_else">
    <ogc:And>
      <ogc:Function name="greaterEqualThan">
        <ogc:Function name="jsonpointer">
          <ogc:PropertyName>props</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>/DRVAL1</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function>
        <ogc:Function name="env">
          <ogc:Literal>SAFETY_CONTOUR</ogc:Literal>
          <ogc:Literal>30.0</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function>
      </ogc:Function>
      <ogc:Function name="greaterThan">
        <ogc:Function name="jsonpointer">
          <ogc:PropertyName>props</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>/DRVAL2</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function>
        <ogc:Function name="env">
          <ogc:Literal>SAFETY_CONTOUR</ogc:Literal>
          <ogc:Literal>30.0</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function>
      </ogc:Function>
    </ogc:And>
  </ogc:Function>
  <ogc:Literal>#ff0000</ogc:Literal>
  <ogc:Literal>#00ff00</ogc:Literal>
</CssParameter>

But it does not work.
The error messages:
line 17: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.opengis.net/ogc":And}'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/ogc":expression}' is expected.
line 18: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.opengis.net/ogc":Function}'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/ogc":comparisonOps, "http://www.opengis.net/ogc":spatialOps, "http://www.opengis.net/ogc":logicOps}' is expected.

Where's the alternative methods

A function cannot take a filter as an argument, it can only take another function. The following might work ("And" as a function has been added around 2020, won't work if your GeoServer is older):
<CssParameter name="fill">
  <ogc:Function name="if_then_else">
    <ogc:Function name="And">
      <ogc:Function name="greaterEqualThan">
        <ogc:Function name="jsonpointer">
          <ogc:PropertyName>props</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>/DRVAL1</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function>
        <ogc:Function name="env">
          <ogc:Literal>SAFETY_CONTOUR</ogc:Literal>
          <ogc:Literal>30.0</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function>
      </ogc:Function>
      <ogc:Function name="greaterThan">
        <ogc:Function name="jsonpointer">
          <ogc:PropertyName>props</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>/DRVAL2</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function>
        <ogc:Function name="env">
          <ogc:Literal>SAFETY_CONTOUR</ogc:Literal>
          <ogc:Literal>30.0</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function>
      </ogc:Function>
    </ogc:Function>
  </ogc:Function>
  <ogc:Literal>#ff0000</ogc:Literal>
  <ogc:Literal>#00ff00</ogc:Literal>
</CssParameter>

